# php - Updating data in database base on id?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on a project that takes students attendance in class and I want to update the database data through PHP whilst running a SQL function of UPDATE, but I want to be able to update it base on the id of the data.

This is the code that I am working with at the moment.

```html
<?php

require_once './dba.php';

$status = "";

if(isset($_POST['time_in'])) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO nameOfTable (datetime) VALUES (NOW())";

    $d = $conn->prepare($query);

    $d->execute();     

} elseif(isset($_POST['time_out'])) {
    $query = "UPDATE nameOfTable SET datetime = NOW() WHERE id = ? ";

    $d = $conn->prepare($query);

    $d->execute();     
} else {
    $status = "Can't time in!";
}
```

Comment: You forgot to call `$d->bind_param()` to provide a value for the `?` placeholder.

Comment: Are you using MySQLI or PDO?

Comment: Where do you get the ID to update from?

Comment: @Barmar using PDO

Comment: @Barmar ID is the id of the time in

Comment: There is no need to use a prepared statement with the INSERT query -- you aren't binding any values.

Comment: You mean the value of `$_POST['time_out']`?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. You want the ID that was created by `AUTO_INCREMENT` when you inserted the previous time. Set a session variable from `$conn->lastInsertId()`, and use that when they clock out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$conn->lastInsertId()` to get the ID that was assigned when they clocked in. Save that in a session variable and use it when they clock out.

```
<?php

require_once './dba.php';

$status = "";

if(isset($_POST['time_in'])) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO nameOfTable (datetime) VALUES (NOW())";
    $d = $conn->prepare($query);
    $d->execute();     
    $_SESSION['clock_id'] = $conn->lastInsertId();
} elseif(isset($_POST['time_out'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['clock_id'])) {
      $status = "You need to clock in first!";
    } else {
      $query = "UPDATE nameOfTable SET datetime = NOW() WHERE id = :id ";
      $d = $conn->prepare($query);
      $d->execute(['id' => $_SESSION['clock_id']]);   
    }
} else {
    $status = "Can't time in!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remember to prepare the query and bind the parameters onto it.

Use the `$id` variable to prepare the query with the appropriate ID.

Make sure you authenticate the session before passing the ID to the query, otherwise an attacker can manipulate this data to pull anyone's data they wish.

```
// Its helpful to create elements within the code to bind onto. :id is ours.
$query = "UPDATE nameOfTable SET datetime = NOW() WHERE id = :id ";

$d = $conn->prepare($query);

// Run the query & bind id to :id
$d->execute(['id' => $id]);
```

Comment: Do I need to define variable $id to run $d->execute? It is returning me that debug result

Comment: Yes. Make sure you define $id. 
If you want to test, you can do $id = 1 if you have a row with id of 1 :)

Comment: But what if I want to update without specifiying id of 1, 2, etc

Comment: Where would you like to get the ID from? What is the purpose of this script? :) 
You can use $_POST and $_GET to practice. If you dont want to use these, you can use a $_SESSION variable.

Depends what you want to do. I'll help you out, just clarify what you need.

Comment: If you aren't going to specify the `id` value, then you don't need to use a prepared statement and your UPDATE will affect **EVERY** row in your table.  Be sure that that behavior is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You try update

```
    $query = "UPDATE nameOfTable SET datetime = NOW() WHERE id = :id ";

    $d = $conn->prepare($query);

    $d->execute(['id' => $id ]);
```

Comment: Do I need to define variable $id to run $d->execute? It is returning me that debug result

Comment: @s.alonzo Of course you do. How else would it know which ID you want to update?